# C++ boost::mpl::type forward declaration

Tags: c++, boost, forward-declaration

I have the following type:

```
typedef boost::mpl::fold<hostObjectTypes, void, base>::type caClientObject;
```

and i need a forward decleration of this caClientObject. Does anyone know how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do

```
struct caClientObject; /* forward */
```

and later

```
struct caClientObject : boost::mpl::fold<hostObjectTypes, void, base> {
};
```